# How to get Laravel group array data total count?

Tags: php, laravel

***Hi, I am trying to get Laravel group array data total can anyone help me ?***

controller code

```php
public function last_10_days_reports()
    {
        $day_10 = Carbon::today()->subDays(10)->format('Y-m-d');
        $leads = Lead::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $day_10)
            ->get()
            ->sortBy('created_at')
            ->groupBy(function ($item) {
                return $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
            })->toArray();

        return $leads;
    }
```

I get like below screenshot data but I want to total array number. can anyone help me ?

http://prntscr.com/159d9fu

Comment: $leads = Lead::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $day_10)->groupBy('created_at')
            ->get() what about this

Comment: Do you need result, like ['2021-06-12' => 5, '2021-06-11' => 4, ...] ?

Comment: @JohnLobo getting error 

http://prntscr.com/159f4bo

Comment: @AndrewMarkhai Exactly I want

Comment: try    'strict' => false, in database.php for mysql

Comment: @JoneySpark, I wrote answer, try it

Comment: @JoneySpark, no problem! Please, accept my answer

Comment: @JoneySpark .If Andrew answer helped you to solve you issue then please accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Lead::query()
            ->selectRaw('date(created_at) as date, count(*) as count')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $day_10)
            ->orderByRaw('date(created_at)')
            ->groupByRaw('date(created_at)')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('count', 'date')
            ->toArray();
```